# How do I transfer from my computers icloud to my 6S iphone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-transfer

I just bought a new 6S iPhone. How do I transfer all my old 6 iPhone to my new phone.  I have loaded icloud onto my computer and think I backed up my old phones data.  Now.... how do transfer from icloud on my computer to my new 6Siphone?

Answer (score 1):

After you have all neccessary data on iCloud, then put your SIM card into your new iPhone and turn it on. Begin setting your iPhone up. You will be prompted to select a Wi-Fi network and language. Then, choose Restore from iCloud backup. Use your Apple ID to sign into your iCloud account. Click Next, and agree to the Terms and Conditions. Choose your most recent backup from the list of options and enter your iCloud password if you are prompted to do so.
https://macback.us/tutorials/how-to-transfer-data-from-iphone-5-5s-to-iphone-6-6s/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot transfer any iCloud data from a computer to a phone. You have not stored any iCloud data on your computer. iCloud data is stored in the location the name implies--the cloud. Have you been regularly  backing up to iCloud? Go to Settings->iCloud->Backup and see when the last backup was. Then, on the new iPhone, select restore from iCloud backup, and it will automatically download all your settings, wallpapers, photos, and apps from the previous phone. Depending on your WiFi, this may take some time. You may view [this article](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521?locale=en_US) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to bring all your data to your new phone would be:

1. start iTunes
2. connect your old phone using a USB cable
3. do a backup on your computer
4. unconnected the old phone
5. connect the new phone using a USB cable
6. restore from backup

Even if you have a iCloud backup this will normally be faster. This works with a Mac or Windows computer. See also:

- [Restore your device from an iCloud or iTunes backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184)
- [How to erase your iOS device and then set it up as a new device or restore it from backups](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204686)